# Type error ajax is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, joomla3.0

I am using JQuery Ajax function with php to check if email exists.
This is working fine when using core-php.
But when I am integrating the same in Joomla Page using Sourcer, I am getting the error in firebug console.

`TypeError: $.ajax is not a function`

The total code for JQuery and the form is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="form/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.jQuery) {  
    alert("Jquery loaded!");
} else {
    alert("Jquery not loaded!");
}

function checkemail()
{
 var email=document.getElementById( "Email" ).value;

 if(email)
 {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'form/checkdata.php',
  data: {
   user_email:email,
  },
  success: function (response) {
   $( '#email_status' ).html(response);
   if(response=="OK")   
   {
    return true;    
   }
   else
   {
    return false;   
   }
  }
  });
 }
 else
 {
  $( '#email_status' ).html("");
  return false;
 }
}

function checkall()
{

 var emailhtml=document.getElementById("email_status").innerHTML;

 if((emailhtml)=="OK")
 {
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="insertdata.php" onsubmit="return checkall();">

 <input type="text" name="email" id="Email" onkeyup="checkemail();">
 <span id="email_status"></span>
 <br>
 <input type="password" name="userpass" id="UserPassword">
 <br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something's probably calling `jQuery.noConflict()` and overriding `$`. Your initial test can check to make sure that `$ === jQuery`.

Comment: @Pointy Wouldn't that cause a `Cannot get member ajax of undefined` error?

Comment: @Pointy - It looks like you are pointing it in the right direction. cause when I am making a initial check before `function checkemail()` I am getting `jquery is loaded` but If I am putting the check after `if email` there is no alert, but once I start inputting some thing in the email field, I am getting the alert `jquery is not loaded`

Comment: @Carcigenicate not if `$` was redefined as some other object.

Comment: @Pointy Ah, good point.

Comment: Short answer, use `jQuery.ajax()` and `jQuery("#email_status")` instead.

Comment: @miken32 - it's wierd. if I am using `jQuery.ajax()` I am still getting `TypeError: jQuery.ajax(...) is not a function`

Comment: are you using a slim version of jQuery with no akax in it? Is path to jquery file correct ( check if it is loading in browser dev tools network)

Comment: Try replacing your `<script src="form/js/jquery.js"></script>` with `<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: @miken32 - I used your suggestion. but the result is the same error. with additional error like `The hash contained in the integrity attribute has the wrong length.  business-owners-form
None of the “sha256” hashes in the integrity attribute match the content of the subresource.`